# How can I weight a column with a number, R?

Tags: r, dataframe, weighting

I have a column with anomaly values and I want to weight it with a specific number representing the number of years (32).

How can I do this?

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$weight<-apply(mtcars[5], 1, ??, 32)
```

Comment: Is this solving your problem `mtcars[5]*32`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mtcars$weighted <- mtcars$drat * 32
```

Or if your weights are different for each observation

```
mtcars$weighted <- mtcars$drat * mtcars$cyl
```

No need for apply, multiplication is already vectorized for your convenience ;)